# How to retrieve a large amount of data from a website

Tags: jquery, json

I want to fill a text area field with a json that is allocated in a web page, I am using a `XMLHttpRequest()` to do it, when the data is small, I'm able to retrieve it but when is big the code stops on the parse json and don't go further. I wonder how can I retrieve a large amount of data?

The json I want to retrieve:

```
[{"description": "APRESENTAÇÃO Nos últimos meses, o Brasil vem assistindo a uma série de retrocessos no campo dos direitos humanos. Direitos fundamentais de todos os brasileiros e brasileiras, garantidos pela Constituição de 1988, vêm sendo continuamente relativizados por um conservadorismo extremo que lança mão, de forma sistemática e com cada vez mais convicção, de violência praticada pelo Estado contra setores já vulnerabilizados. Enquanto o ano de 2018 terminou em clima de grandes incertezas a respeito do então novo cenário para a sociedade civil organizada em torno da defesa de direitos, o de 2019 consolidou a percepção de que se institucionalizou um projeto para atacar, criminalizar, desmobilizar e inviabilizar as lutas sociais no país. O Fundo Brasil entende que o trabalho realizado por grupos, coletivos e organizações da sociedade civil que trabalham na defesa dos direitos humanos precisa ser fortalecido para que seja capaz de resistir às crescentes violações impostas pelo presente cenário político. Acreditamos que apoiar a resistência desses grupos é fundamental para garantir a estabilidade da democracia no país, sem a qual a luta pelo direito a uma vida digna para todas e todos fica severamente comprometida. O compromisso do Fundo Brasil é trabalhar para o fortalecimento e articulação desses grupos da sociedade civil, disponibilizando recursos para o apoio a projetos voltados à defesa de direitos. Para nós, a causa dos direitos humanos só será vitoriosa com o fortalecimento de um amplo conjunto de organizações capazes de se articular e imprimir uma nova dinâmica a esse tipo de trabalho. Com o edital geral “Resistência”, o Fundo Brasil vai apoiar grupos, coletivos e organizações da sociedade civil que dispõem de poucos recursos e/ou que têm dificuldade de acesso a outras fontes de financiamento (vide “Critérios para concorrer ao edital”, item 2, abaixo). O Fundo Brasil também valorizará propostas que pretendam estimular o trabalho em rede, bem como aquelas apresentadas por organizações, grupos ou coletivos coordenados por jovens. ÁREAS PRIORITÁRIAS O edital “Resistência” pretende apoiar iniciativas de enfrentamento aos retrocessos no campo dos direitos humanos, tendo por foco, entre outros: – Projetos que tenham como objetivo a defesa dos direitos das mulheres, com especial atenção às mulheres negras, indígenas e de populações tradicionais. A escalada do pensamento conservador nas diversas esferas da sociedade e instâncias de poder dificulta a histórica luta pela igualdade de gênero, consolidando um cenário de naturalização das violações de direitos que precisa ser combatido; – Projetos que tenham como objetivo o enfrentamento dos diversos tipos de violência, inclusive a violência do Estado, em relação às populações negras, indígenas, tradicionais e LGBTI+ e que tenham sido concebidos considerando aspectos interseccionais da opressão enfrentada por estes grupos; – Projetos que tenham como objetivo a defesa do direito à terra e ao território. A luta de povos indígenas, quilombolas, populações tradicionais, trabalhadores/as rurais e comunidades extrativistas ficou ainda mais intensa nos últimos anos, o que se expressa nos índices alarmantes de violência no campo, conflitos e ameaças crescentes a defensores de direitos socioambientais; – Projetos que tenham como objetivo a defesa do direito à valorização e defesa das religiões de matriz africana, uma vez que a Constituição Federal consagra como direito fundamental a liberdade de consciência e de crença, tendo o Estado a obrigação de proteger a garantia do livre exercício de todas as religiões, condenando a intolerância e o fanatismo; – Projetos que tenham como objetivo a defesa dos direitos dos/as refugiados/as, pessoas que foram forçadas a deixar seus países de origem devido a conflitos ou em razão de perseguições por conta de sua raça, religião, nacionalidade, grupo social ou opinião política. Muitos são vítimas recorrentes de violações de direitos, tais como o direito à documentação relativa à sua condição migratória e restrição de acesso ao mercado de trabalho e aos serviços públicos de saúde e educação; – Projetos que tenham como objetivo o fortalecimento institucional de organizações de defesa de direitos humanos que visem realizar trabalhos de enfrentamento ao desmonte de programas e políticas públicas nas áreas de educação, saúde (inclusive na sua interface com o enfrentamento à atual política de drogas) e trabalho, cujos retrocessos podem aprofundar ainda mais a histórica desigualdade social no Brasil. VALORES DOS APOIOS EM 2020 Em 2020, com o edital ”Resistência”, o Fundo Brasil irá doar até R$ 800.000,00 para projetos cujos objetivos alinhem-se aos do presente edital. O valor dos projetos é de até R$40.000,00, e sua duração, de até 12 meses. CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um projeto; As organizações, grupos ou coletivos proponentes de projetos devem ter receita anual de, no m CRITÉRIOS PARA CONCORRER AO EDITAL Cada organização, grupo ou coletivo poderá apresentar apenas um p "}]
```

My code:

```
function NoticeTitleChange(selectNotice) {
$("#noticeDescriptioN").val("Carregando Descrição...");

var parameters = selectNotice.value;
var url = "/FirstAccessRegister/CustomActionNotice/?action=GetNoticeDescription&parameters=" + parameters;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onerror = function (error) { alert(JSON.stringify(error)); };
req.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if (req.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (req.status == 200)
        {
            var notice = JSON.parse(req.response);
            for (var i = 0; i < notice.length; i++)
            {

                $("#noticeDescriptioN").val(notice[i].description);
            }
          }
       }
    }

    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send();
}
```

The code is working on the part to retrieve the data, but when I debug the code and reaches the line:

```
var notice = JSON.parse(req.response);
```

the code doesn't go any further. Is this a time out, how could solve it ?

Comment: What means "code dont go further", are there any error in console?

Comment: Go to the console and type `var myVar='[{"description": "my long description"]'`. Then hit enter and just type `JSON.parse(myVar)[0].description`. You will see that it's ok. Console log `req.response` and check whether it's a string or an object

Comment: I press f10 on any browser console and i cant continue debugging after the json parse

Comment: Taking the json from the question and putting it in the browser console, it parses fine.  Also going solely off of the size of the json you provided, I can assure you that is not a large request body.  Projects I work on have api endpoints that return json responses **much** larger than that, and work fine.

Comment: @Taplar, i am using a assyncronous way to retrieve the information, if its possible that when the json its parsing, the XMLHttpRequest is giving time out ?